# Migrate OS to new SSD without upgrade?

Tags: macos, migration

I bought a new SSD for my Macbook Pro early 2015 and tried to migrate to it yesterday.  I'm still on Big Sur, and of course internet recovery forced me to upgrade to Monteray at the same time.  It worked, but I discovered that it could no longer access my NAS over SMB.  Presumably Monteray has broken this in some way and I have to wait for either Apple or AVM to come up with a fix.  In the meantime I'm back to the original SSD.

Is there any way for me to migrate my OS to the new SSD without upgrading to Monteray at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I need to install an old version of macOS

1. Grab a USB stick with at least 8GB
2. Get a [dosdude1 tool](http://dosdude1.com/software.html), use it only for downloading a full version of macOS from Apple's site
3. Create a [bootable USB](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372)

And finally, you have a USB stick with a macOS installer of the version you prefer ready to be used.

Comment: I eventually followed the same solution as documented [here](https://osxdaily.com/2021/03/24/how-create-macos-big-sur-bootable-install-drive/).  I didn't use the tool you listed, since it can be done using system software that's already installed from the command line: "softwareupdate --fetch-full-installer --full-installer-version 11.6.1" and then "sudo /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Big\ Sur.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/Untitled --nointeraction", where /Volumes/Untitled is my USB stick.

Comment: Thank you for the new way of doing it, will be using this one.

Answer (score 1):

> of course internet recovery forced me to upgrade to Monteray

You don't have to install the latest OS. Which one you're offered depends on what startup key combo you use:

> On an Intel-based Mac, if you use Shift-Option-Command-R during startup, you're offered the macOS that came with your Mac, or the closest version still available. **If you use Option-Command-R during startup, in most cases you're offered the latest macOS that is compatible with your Mac**. Otherwise you're offered the macOS that came with your Mac, or the closest version still available.

It sounds like you used <kbd>⌘⌥R</kbd>, but should use <kbd>⇧⌘⌥R</kbd> instead.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904

Comment: That worked, it allows me to get to El Capitan.  However it seems that El Capitan doesn't have the driver for the new SSD, an Aura Pro X2.  So I wasn't able to use that to restore my system onto the new drive.